# Powermock 1.6.3 with Javassist 3.18.2-GA produces a NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, javassist, powermockito

I am using Powermock 1.6.3 with Javassist 3.18.2-GA, Mockito 1.10.19, JUnit 4.11 and JDK1.8. I did not write the tests or the test classes and therefore, I am not very familiar with these libraries. Did not have any problems building on JDK1.7. I have been assigned the task to uplift the application to JDK1.8 and that is when I encountered this error first. Also, the errors occur only in those test classes that mock classes that have static methods or have methods that call static methods (the test classes that use the PowerMockito.mockStatic() method). I have spent a lot of time working on the issue and I feel like I have reached a dead end. Any help will be much appreciated. Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.CtMethod.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.removeTestAnnotationsForTestMethodsThatRunOnOtherClassLoader(TestClassTransformer.java:185)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.transform(TestClassTransformer.java:198)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:250)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:179)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:145)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

P.S. I have tried many different combinations of Javassist and Powermock and all of them have resulted in errors.

Comment: Finally : you might better ask your question at Google groups,  the powermock folks have their own group there. Better chance for reasonable feedback there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power Mock 1.6.3 is [compiled against Javassist 3.20.0-GA](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.powermock%7Cpowermock-core%7C1.6.3%7Cjar). If this results in a `NoSuchMethodError`, make sure no other library on your class path requires a newer version of Javassist.

Comment: Thank you so much! Built the classpath and found another library using Javassist 3.4.GA. Works fine now.

Comment: @JayanthAvasarala Which library uses Javassist 3.4.GA? Did you change it in some way?

Comment: @Rafael Winterhalter What is the connection between other library requiring a different version of Javaassist with Power Mock's? Is the former in the way of the latter getting the right version?

Comment: You have to query your build tool for a dependeny tree to see what other library requires Javassist.

Comment: What would be the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. As mentioned by Rafael, the Issue was due to having a conflicting Javassist version. Since my project is a maven build project, I use the following to view the [dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true
```

From the output, I could find which component has Javassist as a transitive dependency. Then using maven [dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions), removed that conflicting version from the classpath.

Hope this would be helpful